# Recursive function in assembly

Tags: c, recursion, assembly

I have a method `fun_times` in assembly code:

```
fun_times:
   pushq %rbp
   movq %rsp, %rbp
   subq $32, %rsp
   movq %rdi, -24(%rbp)
   movl %esi, -28(%rbp)
   cmpl $0, -28(%rbp)
   jne .L2
   movl $0, -4(%rbp)
   jmp .L3
.L2
   movl $0, -4(%rbp)
   jmp .L4
.L5
   movl -4(%rbp), %eax
   movslq %eax, %rdx
   movq -24(%rbp), %rax
   addq %rdx, %rax
   movzbl (%rax), %eax
   movsbl %al, %eax
   addl %eax, -8(%rbp)
   addl $1, -4(%rbp)
.L4
   movl -4(%rbp), %eax
   cmpl -28(%rbp), %eax
   jl .L5
   movl -28(%rbp), %eax
   leal -1(%rax), %edx
   movq -24(%rbp), %rax
   movl %edx, %esi
   movq %rax, %rdi
   call fun_times
   movl %eax, %eax
   movl -8(%rbp), %eax
   addl %edx, %eax
.L3:
   leave
   ret
```

I wonder what does `fun_times` do and is it possible to write it in C code or pseudo code. Also, how many bytes is allocated on the stack with each all to `fun_times`? 32?

Finally, where is the result(i.e., return value) stored? `%eax`?

I would be really happy if someone could explain this function to me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please, take the [tour] and review [ask] a question.

Comment: So, where did you get this code?  Is this a homework project?  How is this code called?  Is this linux (ie not Windows)? "bytes allocated on the stack" Hint: What (exactly) does `call` do?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to write it in C because it looks like gcc output targeting the x86-64 System V ABI (where return values go in EAX/RAX like all other common x86 calling conventions).  So the asm isn't doing anything you couldn't get a compiler to emit.  Probably from `gcc -O0`, which is why it's storing/reloading all the time.  Use a debugger to single-step it if you want to see what it does.  For stack consumption, don't forget about the `push %rbp` and that `call` pushes a return address.